# Wordpress installed with Elastick BeanStalk overwrites uploaded images

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Wordpress instance on Amazon Elastic BeanStalk. When I upload instance with EB scripts, the whole page is being replaced, also uploaded images which can be attached to posts. And after such automatic deploy, posts have missing pictures:)

I tried to solve this:
1) I logged into Amazon machine with SFTP, but my user ec2-user has only read-access to files. So I was not able overwrite only part of application, with retaining uploaded files.

2) I read I can use Amazon S3 as external storage for upload files. This is still not tested by me:). Do you know if this is good approach?

3) Any other approach for this problem? How to organize it on amazon: machine backup probably should be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elastic Beanstalk environment is essentially stateless; meaning that all data that is persisted to disk will be lost when the application is updated, the server is rebuilt or the environment scales.

The best way in my option is to use a plugin that writes all media files to AWS S3; something similar to the [Amazon S3 and Cloudfront](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) plugin.

You log files should also be shipped to a remote syslog server which you can either build yourself or use a 3rd party.

**Google:** loggly, logstash, graylog, splunk

Comment: yes, I found this solution too, but additionally I have to do probably any backups on Amazon if case of any crash? OR this S3 is very secure (probably)?

Comment: "AWS will use commercially reasonable efforts to make Amazon S3 available with a Monthly Uptime Percentage (defined below) of at least 99.9% during any monthly billing cycle (the “Service Commitment”). In the event Amazon S3 does not meet the Service Commitment, you will be eligible to receive a Service Credit as described below."

That is the SLA agreement directly from AWS site. If you're still not comfortable then you can sync your S3 buckets between regions to insure data integrity.

Comment: Good I will give you myu mark for this:) . I implemented S3 yesterday. My question is... if there is need or possibility to do backups of S3 content

Comment: Rather have backups and not need them, than need backups and not have them.